# Finite projective chain complex acyclic iff isomorphic to direct sum of shifts

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let $\dots \to 0 \to M_n\to M_{n-1}\to\dots\to M_0\to 0 \to \dots$ be a complex of projective modules. Prove that this complex is acyclic (zero homology) iff the complex is isomorphic to the direct sum of complexes of the form $M\xrightarrow{id}M$ with shifts.

(Note: The shifted complex $M[r]$ is the complex which in degree n is $M_{n+r}$, with differential $d_{M[r]} = (−1)^rd_M$.)

I have proved that a finite complex of projective is acyclic iff the identity morphism is homotopic to the 0 morphism, but I'm not sure if this is on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the final map $\pi:M_1\to M_0$. This is a surjection, so splits, because
$M_0$ is projective. There's a splitting map $i:M_0\to M_1$ with $\pi\circ i
=\text{id}_{M_0}$. Then $M_1$ is the direct sum of $\ker\pi=M_1'$ and $\text{im}\, i=M_0'$. Both these are projective, and the original exact sequence splits into
two exact sequences
$$0\to M_n\to M_{n-1}\to\cdots\to M_2\to M_1'\to0\to0$$
and
$$0\to 0\to 0\to\cdots\to 0\to M_0'\to M_0\to0.$$
Now induct on the length of sequence.

Comment: Where do we use the fact that M is isomorphic to the direct sum of shifts?